# SharePoint hosted app for SharePoint public site

Tags: public-website

Is it possible to have a SharePoint hosted app for SharePoint public site  collection, even though there are no site-features, solutions, or catalog menus in the site settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can create apps for SharePoint that can be used by anonymous users on public-facing Microsoft SharePoint 2013 sites.

[How to: Create apps for SharePoint that can be used by anonymous users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579415.aspx)

[What Every Developer Needs to Know About SharePoint Apps, CSOM, and Anonymous Publishing Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Waqas for your reference, while looking into that. I came  through its limitations which involves one of my scenario. I need to display the names of all the files from one of my document library on this site which will be downloadable to anonymous users.

Comment: yeah, there is always a limit.

Comment: i can see on my libarary having anonymous access as View items. so can we make anonymous user to view the list items using sharepoint-hosted  apps?

Comment: i m not developer so i cant tell you about it. may be open another question with detailed requirement.

Comment: Created a simple sharepoint hosted app - which will retrieve listItem from one of my list ,and display its Title on default.aspx of the app. Published the app on dev site, and added the app to my public site .But the issue i am facing is- I  could not find my app , while trying to add app onto my Page.